# ELMAH is not logging on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, elmah

I try to use elmah to log errors on my server. If exception occurs on my local pc, elmah will save this error. But after I upload it to azure, it doesn't work anymore. Database configuration is correct, because I can log errors with the following statement (Local/Azure):

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
```

I suggest it's configuration error, because azure has a different IIS version and also different server configuation.

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration.RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling, Version=5.1.1209.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.TypeRegistrationProvidersConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <RetryPolicyConfiguration defaultRetryStrategy="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy">
    <incremental name="Incremental Retry Strategy" maxRetryCount="5" retryIncrement="00:00:03" />
    <fixedInterval name="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy" maxRetryCount="6" retryInterval="00:00:04" />
    <exponentialBackoff name="Exponential Backoff Retry Strategy" />
  </RetryPolicyConfiguration>
  <typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>
    <clear />
    <add name="Caching" sectionName="cachingConfiguration" />
    <add name="Cryptography" sectionName="securityCryptographyConfiguration" />
    <add name="Exception Handling" sectionName="exceptionHandling" />
    <add name="Instrumentation" sectionName="instrumentationConfiguration" />
    <add name="Logging" sectionName="loggingConfiguration" />
    <add name="Policy Injection" sectionName="policyInjection" />
    <add name="Security" sectionName="securityConfiguration" />
    <add name="Data Access" providerType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" />
    <add name="Validation" providerType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Configuration.ValidationTypeRegistrationProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation" />
    <add sectionName="RetryPolicyConfiguration" name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" />
  </typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" name="elmah" connectionString="..." />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/#login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="7200" />
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <pages enableSessionState="false" enableViewState="false" validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <sessionState mode="Off" timeout="120" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.1209.0" newVersion="5.1.1209.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="2.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/error404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah" applicationName="..." />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you verify that the handler works? if you go to yoursite/elmah.axd do you get an error?

Comment: Also, how are you deploying to Azure? directly from Visual Studio or are you deploying from TFS? Is it an Azure Website or an Azure Compute Cloud Service?

Comment: Yes, the handler works. I can go to elmah.axd and see the errors I puted manually with `Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e)`. But Elmah don't log server errors (http error code 500).

Comment: I use Azure Websites and I only need to check in my code. [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) automatically deploy new code to azure servers. But I don't think that this is the problem. I think there is something wrong with the configuration above and IIS settings on Azure.

Comment: I just compared your web.config to the one I have in a similar Azure website and I can find no error on it. I'm stumped :S

Comment: Are you using Table Storage? If so, you might want to use the NuGet package to install ELMAH. http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/using-elmah-in-windows-azure-with-table-storage/

Comment: I use Azure SQL and regular Elmah nuget package for Sql Server. But it works correctly, because I can log exceptions manually as I wrote above. But it seems that the elmah handler not triggered by exception for some reason.

Comment: Where are you raising the error event? In your RoleEntryPoint?

Comment: The problem might be with the creation of the Database in SQL Azure. Use this script for SQL Azure: http://blog.redjungle.com/post/2013/01/22/Elmah-and-Azure-Using-Sql-Azure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity sake, remove the Elmah handlers from the `<location>` node and move them back under the `<system.web>`  and `<system.webServer>` nodes and see if that work. I know it's not an ideal solution, but it will ensure that you're logging is working out of the box with no special handling.

I'm suggesting this because I am having the exact same problem with Elmah on Azure. It was working find without being handled in a  node, but the minute I moved it to secure it, stopped working. I haven't had time to dig into the root cause yet, but this might give you something to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already solved this so just in case - when comparing my web.config with yours, you seems to be missing `<modules>` section from `<system.webServer>` node. Same apply for `<system.web>` node.

Here is mine:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Again, note `<httpModules>` and `<modules>` nodes.